# How do I check for failure in AWS Lambda that throws an Exception in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I doing a basic set of TDD on AWS Lambda, and noticing that if I create a simple test function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // Will always fail
    throw "Failed to execute - this is a failure function that will always fail";
};
```

That when I invoke it through the SDK with com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest the response code for this function always comes back as 200, and the Error Log is empty!

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in terms of invoking and asking for errors here; because it seems crazy that a JavaScript function that throws an Exception, and, when I test it reports as execution failed in the AWS Lambda console would return a 200?

I noticed that I'm using the async variant here; so I tried also with a sync variant and a context.fail() call:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // Will always fail
    try {
        throw "Failed to execute - this is a failure function that will always fail";
    }
    catch(e) {
        context.fail(e);
    }
};
```

I would definitely expect this to return a 500 or something, but again, I get a 200!

Comment: what do you mean by error log? I tried your example and get a {"errorMessage": "Failed to execute - this is a failure function that will always fail"} and it is written to CloudWatch as well

Comment: 200 means the invocation was successful (the call was executed and *some* response was returned). It says nothing about what was returned. The exception should be written in the Payload. In general, direct invocation is different from HTTP integration (via API Gateway).

Answer (score 0):

Lambda has [two invocation types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html).

1. RequestResponse (synchronous)
2. event (asynchronous)

As you can see, the problem might not necessarily exist within your lambda function. My suggestion would be to check your code that invokes this lambda to see what kind of invocation type you are using.

Comment: I'm relatively sure it's RequestResponse - but I'm gonna double check